# cx_freeze with docx package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, cx-freeze

setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["lxml","tkinter","win32timezone","docx"] }

setup(  name = "ProgramGUI",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Telephone History Tracer",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("Telephone History Tracer.py")],
        )
```

This builds fine.

When running the program I get the error:

```
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at'C:\Python33\build\exe.win32-3.3\library.zip\docx\templates\default.docx'
```

I have manually pasted `templates` folder into `...library.zip\docx\` (which contains the default.docx file), but I'm still getting the same error.

I'd really appreciate some advise on this one.

Comment: It sounds like docx can't load data files from inside a zip file. You may have to tweak it's code to look somewhere else for that file. See [using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the FAQ.